# How to make sense of OpenShift pods CPU usage metrics

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-enterprise

Can someone please help explain how to understand the CPU usage metrics reported on the OpenShift web console.

Below is an example for my application.  The cursor on the graph points to 0.008 cores and is different at different times.  What does 0.008 cores mean?  How should this value be understood if my project on OpenShift doesn't resource limit and quote set?  Thanks!

[image: CPU usage]

Answer (score 3):

Compute Resources Learn More

Each container running on a node uses compute resources like CPU and memory. You can specify how much CPU and memory a container needs to improve scheduling and performance.

CPU
CPU is often measured in units called millicores. Each millicore is equivalent to 1⁄1000 of a CPU core.

1000 millcores  =  1 core